# Почему код на js возвращает не boolean значение?

Tags: javascript

```
function foo (object) {
    return object && object.property
}

foo({property: 'test'}) // test
```

Почему такой код возвращает не boolean значение а значение свойства?

Comment: `function foo (object) {
    return (object.property && object);
}

console.log(foo({property: 'test'})) // test` а так возвращает объект :D

Comment: так решил создатель языка, https://learn.javascript.ru/logical-ops

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что выражение эквивалентно:

```
function foo (object) {
    return object.property
}

foo({property: 'test'}) // test
```

Comment: Нет, выше в комментарии @stranger-in-the-q ответил на вопрос. "Если левый аргумент – false, оператор И возвращает его и заканчивает вычисления. Иначе – вычисляет и возвращает правый аргумент."

Comment: вопрос был про то, что логическое И в других языках возвращает не аргумент, а булевый результат. в js иное поведение

Comment: Не эквивалентно. Для вызова `foo(null)`, например, результат будет разным.